# Issue : log-rotate is not working

Tags: linux, logging, cron, logrotate

I am configuring log rotation one of my production server. I am having a weired issue. I have configured the log rotation for a file on daily basis.

But unfortunately the rotation is not working.  I have checked the status of the "/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status", It says the file has been rotated successfully. But it is not

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/yum.log" 2019-1-4-14:0:0
"/var/log/chef/client.log" 2019-4-14-3:33:2
"/var/log/boot.log" 2019-1-10-3:46:1
"/usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/stdout.log" 2019-4-15-3:9:1
"/var/log/chrony/*.log" 2019-1-4-14:0:0
"/var/log/wtmp" 2019-1-4-14:0:0
"/var/log/spooler" 2019-4-14-3:33:2
"/var/log/btmp" 2019-1-4-14:0:0
"/var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log" 2019-1-10-3:0:0
```

The file want to rotate is: `/usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/stdout.log`

Log-rotate config file :

```
/usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/stdout.log {
    daily
    copytruncate
    rotate 7
    compress
    postrotate
       /bin/kill -HUP `cat /usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/connector.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript

}
```

Comment: Please provide the logrotate configuration for that file as well

Comment: Check your logrotate config, if you are rotating based on size then I guess logrotate doesn't adjust the file if the size threshold isn't breached.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider & @kn330 Thank you sir.
Rotation is not based on the size.Please find my log rotation configs file


/usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/stdout.log {
    daily
    copytruncate
    rotate 7
    compress
    postrotate
       /bin/kill -HUP `cat /usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/connector.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript

}

Comment: Please don't add more information as a comment, edit your question instead. It is very hard to read as a comment.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider , sorry, I updated on the description.

Answer (score 1):

try with my logrotate file:
This rotates the logs of apache with the date, and if it ends in 2019 it compresses those files before deleting them.

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        create 0640 root root
        su root adm
        rotate 2
        missingok
        compress
        delaycompress
        dateext
        dateformat -%d-%m-%Y.log
        notifempty
        sharedscripts

        postrotate
        gzip /var/log/apache2/*-2019.log
        service apache2 restart
        rm /var/log/apache2/*.gz
        endscript
}
```

If you want to check or force the execution of a logrotate execute the following command:

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/name_of_your_file
```

and with the verbose mode, you will be able to see what is happening there

Hope this be helpful.